# Reading XML attribute from a processing instruction line

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, attributes, processing-instruction

I have the following line in a XML document

```
<?ish ishref="GUID-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" version="1" lang="ae" srclng="en"?>
```

and want to read (and modify) the lang attribute. I have tried the following:

```
newXMLDoc.Load(XMLfile);
instruction = newXMLDoc.SelectSingleNode("/processing-instruction('ish')")
         as XmlProcessingInstruction;
```

`instruction` returned a valid object with the innerText equal to "it's" line but I don't know how to access the attributes (tried various ways but all return null)

How do I Access the attributes of `instruction` (or is there another way of doing the access better) ?

I have tried XPath like "/ish@lang" and `instruction.Attributes` but those just return NULL.

I would prefer a non LINQ solution, I'm using .NET 4.5

Comment: I have a hunch that a processing instruction doesn't actually - i.e. is not defined to - have attributes. That is, any free text is allowed between the `<? ... ?>` marks, and it's only a coincidence that people usually put something that looks like attributes there.

Comment: That is, as far as any conforming parser is concerned, the content of a PI is just a string, and if you want to parse for attributes, you have to do it yourself.

Comment: If you care to use Saxon as your XPath engine then it has an extension function `saxon:getPseudoAttribute()` designed to do this job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Processing instruction](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-pi) contains just text - the XML specification does not impose any restrictions on the content nor gives any structure to them. So to get the inner text you just use `Value` property:

```
var newXMLDoc = new XmlDocument();
newXMLDoc.LoadXml("<?ish t='v' u='v'?><R></R>");
var instruction = newXMLDoc.SelectSingleNode("/processing-instruction('ish')")
             as XmlProcessingInstruction;
Console.WriteLine(instruction.Value); // t='v' u='v'
```

Parsing of resulting value depends on how strict values of the PI are. Simple `String.Split` on space and than on `'='` may be enough if you know that values don't have spaces, otherwise some more intricate method, maybe RegEx would need to be written.

If format is relatively fixed or you just need to replace something - `string.Replace` (or `RegEx.Replace`) could work:

```
  instruction.Value = instruction.Value.Replace("lang=\"ae\"", "lang=\"XX\"");
```

Comment: I see, yes, it is pretty fixed format, I will use a string.split  and loop over them.